# Obtener el valor de un Select de entrada

Tags: jquery

quiero  obtener el valor de un select sin tener que elegir una opcion y con este valor llenar un input, a lo que me refiero es que si el select viene con primera opcion `texto1` y el `value` es `1` , que al hacer el refresh automaticamente me llene el input sin tener que elegir otra opción del select para que cargue el value `1` del `texto1` . No se si logro explicarme bien , publico mi codigo : 
HTML :

```
 <select name="Proveedor" id="Proveedor" onchange="LLenarInput();"style="width:110px;height:20px;" required>
     <option value="1" >texto1</option>
     <option value="2" >texto2</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="proveedor2">
```

jquery

```
function LLenarInput() {
        var select = document.getElementById("Proveedor");
        document.getElementById("proveedor2").value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por tu pregunta parece que piensas que jQuery es JavaScript, pones la etiqueta [tag:jquery] pero nada en tu código es específico jQuery. Es JavaScript puro y duro.

Comment: jajaj si tenes razon :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien simplemente tienes que asignar el valor en el `$(document).ready()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var select = document.getElementById("Proveedor");
        document.getElementById("proveedor2").value = select.value;
        
});

function LLenarInput() {
    var select = document.getElementById("Proveedor");
    document.getElementById("proveedor2").value = select.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Proveedor" id="Proveedor" style="width:110px;height:20px;" required>
     <option value="1" >texto1</option>
     <option value="2" >texto2</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="proveedor2">
```

**Edito**: Ahora que tengo más tiempo te pongo la solución utilizando `jQuery` (que para eso lo tienes :))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#Proveedor").on("change",function(){
     LLenarInput()
    });
   $("#proveedor2").val($("#Proveedor").val());            
});

function LLenarInput() {
    $("#proveedor2").val($("#Proveedor").val()); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Proveedor" id="Proveedor" onchange="LLenarInput();"style="width:110px;height:20px;" required>
     <option value="1" >texto1</option>
     <option value="2" >texto2</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="proveedor2">
```

[Info](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Gracias hermano